# Move from JSON-RPC to simple RESTful API

Tags: php, web-services, rest, json-rpc

I have a web application that uses JSON-RPC. There is a file rest.php that contains code like this:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonObj = json_decode($body);
switch ($jsonObj->method) {
        case 'API1': //function1

              header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 200 OK");
              break;
        case 'API2': //function2

              header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 200 OK");
              break;
        default:
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 400 Bad request");
            break;
    }
```

the switch structure dispatches the request according to the parameter "method".
I want to change it. I want to create single REST API for each function, each with its URI. So without the parameter "method".

Can someone give me a hint? I have to create a file for each REST API? It is the first time that make REST API in php.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. I personally prefer to dispatch requests through URI routing[1]. If URI routing is not an option, i'd implement lookup table to dispatch requests. For example if there are several resources:

```
/books
/cars
/music
```

i'd handle requests based on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] see[2]. Example:

```
$lookup_table = array(
    '/books' => function($method) {
        switch ($method) {
            case 'GET': {  // handle GET request

            } break;

            case 'POST': {  // handle POST request

          } break;
        }
    },

    '/authors' => function($method) {
        switch ($method) {
            case 'GET': {  // handle GET request

            } break;

            case 'PUT': {  // handle PUT request

          } break;
        }
    }
);

// this is simplification
// REQUEST_URI needs some work before used
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (isset($lookup_table[$uri])) {
    $lookup_table[$uri]($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
}
```

I think this simplified example will give you some hints.

1. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html
2. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php